# Spring project creating a bug in pom.xml need help to fix it

Tags: spring

CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Cannot access central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.1 has not been downloaded from it before.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you're running maven in offline mode? Please check that you don't use `-o` option.

If you have to work in offline mode you should first download all the required dependency (one time):

```
mvn dependency:go-offline
```

Comment: I'm running into this problem myself, except I don't want Maven to be offline. Do you know how I can turn it back online?

Comment: Not sure I understand. By default maven attempts to connect to remote repository and stores everything in the local cache (~/.m2 by default). You can forcefully update the cache by using -U option. Sometimes when the cache is corrupted the best is to remove the folder manually

Comment: I found the problem. I went to Maven in Project Settings and unticked the "work offline" box, which for some reason was enabled after a restart